# Creating a total out of subtotals in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I've been trying to create a program that allows me to take values from a text file and add the prices together and then take those values and create an overall total. So far I've managed to do the first bit I'm just struggling to figure out how to take those new values out of my array and add them together for my overall. I'm fairly new to python and coding in general so I'm not the most knowledgeable person.

```
file =  open("receipt.txt")
tempArray = []
prdCalculation = []
for row in file:
    #split
    field = row.split(",")
    prdID = field[0]
    prdName = field[1]
    prdPrice = float(field[2])
    prdQuan = int(field[3])
    #calc
    subtotal  = round(prdPrice*prdQuan, 2)
    #appending into array
    tempArray.append(prdName)
    tempArray.append(prdPrice)
    tempArray.append(prdQuan)
    tempArray.append(subtotal)
    prdCalculation.append(tempArray)
    tempArray = []

#printing the array
for row in prdCalculation:
    for element in row:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()
```

This is the current code that I am using, struggling to know what to add or change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open("receipt.txt")
prdCalculation = []
total = 0

for row in file:
    field = row.split(",")
    prdID = field[0]
    prdName = field[1]
    prdPrice = float(field[2])
    prdQuan = int(field[3])
   
    subtotal = round(prdPrice * prdQuan, 2)
  
    total += subtotal
    prdCalculation.append([prdID, prdName, prdPrice, prdQuan, subtotal])

for row in prdCalculation:
    for element in row:
        print(element, end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: Works perfect ! Thanks! @gag baghdasaryan
`
input receipt.txt 


1,testproduct1,100,4
2,testproduct2,200,8


Output : 

1 testproduct1 100.0 4 400.0 
2 testproduct2 200.0 8 1600.0  

`
@Original Poster . Can you please check if this is the output that you are interested in